# Split a list into two based on the filters in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

Having a list of countries name, and if I search for a country that starts with B, how do I split  the search with all the countries that begin with B as a list and the remaining countries as another list and then combine the both so that the countries with "B" is at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted(by:)` to achieve your goals. You simply need to check if the current and the next element start with your search term using the `prefix` operator and in case the current element does start with it, but the next one doesn't, sort the current element before the next one, otherwise preserve current order.

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    /// Sorts the array based on whether the elements start with `input` or not
    func searchSort(input: Element) -> Array {
        sorted(by: { current, next in current.hasPrefix(input) && !next.hasPrefix(input) })
    }
}

["Austria", "Belgium", "Brazil", "Denmark", "Belarus"].searchSort(input: "B")
```

Output: `["Belgium", "Brazil", "Belarus", "Austria", "Denmark"]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it for a searchBar? If yes, try this:

```
let filteredCountries = CountriesArray.filter({ (country: String) -> Bool in
            return country.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) && country.hasPrefix(searchText)
        })
```

Also, for sorting try this:

```
let sortedArray =  filteredCountries.sorted(by: { $0.lowercased() < $1.lowercased() })
```

Even if you don't need it for a searchBar, explore filter() method, its very helpfull and easy to use.

Comment: Why make `filteredCountries` a mutable var just to then assign a value to it straight away? You can do `let filteredCountries = CountriesArray.filter...`. Also, your code doesn't actually achieve sorting, only filtering.

Comment: edited my code. thanks. didnt see he asks for sorting too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Dictionary for splitting, it won't sort the key, but you got separated arrays to use:

```
let a = ["FF0000", "000000", "0083FF", "FBE58D", "7A9EB0", "909CE1"]
let b = Dictionary(grouping: a, by: { $0.first! })

print(b) //["0": ["000000", "0083FF"], "7": ["7A9EB0"], "F": ["FF0000", "FBE58D"], "9": ["909CE1"]]
```